# Azure Web App not working: Nothing uploaded to Server

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu

I made a .Net web app that works perfectly in localhost.
After publishing it to Azure Websites via Visual Studio, all I see is the default template "hostingstart.html".

On exploring more using Kudu console, I found out that there is only that file in the wwwroot folder. Why is my app files not there when I have published them via Visual Studio project?

Comment: `hostingstart.html` is there when an web app is first created, so I would say that your deployment was not successful...I am guessing that you are publishing to existing webapps? can you share more detail about your steps? @[Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet) as well

Comment: @watashiSHUN I made a web api using web app in .Net. When I published it first, it was able to publish the website to azure-websites perfectly. But now when I am trying to publish it into new profile(I dont want to disturb the first one that I published), only the main website page is working. Looking into Kudo console, there was only one file in wwwroot folder and that is "hostingstart.html"

Comment: basically you are publishing the same website to two different web apps? to debug this I need to know your publish procedure step by step (preferably with screenshots), can you open an issue on the [kudu project](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues)?

Comment: @watashiSHUN I am right clicking on project and clicking on publish. There I select Microsoft Azure Web App and then create a new profile where I fill in details like resourceGroup, hosting plan etc. Then VS displays the website that I am able to open and the basic template is displayed.

Comment: in visual studio output, you should see:
`2>Adding file ({your_webapp}/{binaries_or_configs}).
2>Publish Succeeded.
2>Web App was published successfully {your_webapp}
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`